# How to declare friend a static locale function

Tags: c++

I have the following code : a template class derived from an interface needs using a static local function. I declared it friend ; however, the function cannot call the private/protected members "within this context".

How to set this static locale function as friend correctly ?

I specify my class is template because owing to that, I cannot use an inline friend function in it (the compiler says my function is redefined).

Furthermore, I cannot change the Interface class.

This is the code :

```
class Interface
{
    protected:
        virtual void virt(void) = 0;
};

static void bar(Interface *b);

template<class T>
class Foo : public Interface
{
    // How to properly say the local function bar is friend ?
    friend void bar(Interface *b);

        T val;

    public:
        void virt(void)
        {
        }

        void func(void)
        {
            bar(this);
        }
};

static void bar(Interface *b)
{
    b->virt(); // Error: virt() is protected.
}

int     main(void)
{
    Foo<int>    foo;

    foo.func();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the `Interface` class then you can simply introduce an intermediary class to get to the protected member:

```
class Interface {
protected:
    virtual void virt(void) = 0;
};

class Interface2 : public Interface {
public:
    virtual void virt(void) = 0;

};

static void bar(Interface2 *b);

template<class T>
class Foo : public Interface2 {
    // How to properly say the local function bar is friend ?
    friend void bar(Interface2 *b);

    T val;

public:
    void virt(void)
    {
    }

    void func(void)
    {
        bar(this);
    }
};

static void bar(Interface2 *b)
{
    b->virt(); // Error: virt() is protected.
}

int     main(void)
{
    Foo<int>    foo;

    foo.func();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`bar` is friend of `Foo`, but not friend of `Interface`. And there's no need to declare `bar` as the friend of `Foo` because it only calls the protected member function on `Interface`. You can declare it as the friend of `Interface`.

```
class Interface;
static void bar(Interface *b);

class Interface
{
    friend void bar(Interface *b);
    protected:
        virtual void virt(void) = 0;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I see I misunderstood the friend concept. However, I accepted the flatmouse answer because he gave to me a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For

```
static void bar(Interface *b)
{
    b->virt(); // Error: virt() is protected.
}
```

to work you'll have to make `bar` a `friend` of `Interface`. Whether it is a `friend` of the derived classes nor not does not make a difference.